# Can I predict on continues target value in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, text-classification

This is the example of data that I have.
Length of df is 1778360.
The search term is the queries that people type on Search Engine.
CR (Conversion Rate) is a continuous number. It starts from 0 to no limit.

```
    Search term                         CR
0   asos french connection lined mac    100
1   hugo boss polo black                50
2   women's pale grey trousers uk       47
3   military jacket                     8
4   girls adidas red tracksuit top      0
```

What I want is to predict the CR with the text as the input.

```
texts = df['Search term']
tags = df['CR']
num_max = 1000

# preprocess
le = LabelEncoder()
tags = le.fit_transform(tags)
token = Tokenizer(num_words=num_max)
token.fit_on_texts(texts)
mat_texts = token.texts_to_matrix(texts, mode='freq')
print(tags[:5])
print(mat_texts[:5])
print(tags.shape, mat_texts.shape)

# split data to train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(mat_texts, tags, train_size=0.8, random_state=1)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=num_max, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

# evaluate the model
train_scores = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print("Train %s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], train_scores[1]*100))
test_scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Test %s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], test_scores[1]*100))
```

I got this as result:
Train acc: 82.53%
Test acc: 82.48%

I'm not sure if the last dense and the loss function is correct. This is more like a linear regression but I couldn't find a suitable keras model for linear regression.

Can somebody help, please? Thanks.

P.s. I'm very new to deep learning and neural network.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it is about machine learning rather than software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/1233251). You can ask these questions on [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [DataScience.SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Is conversion rate actually unbounded or is it a percentage between 0 and 100?  If it's a bounded percentage, then you probably want a single neuron with a sigmoid activation (logit) in the output (and transform your conversion rate data to be on [0,1]).

Answer (score -1):

For regression problem, the activation of the last dense layer should be `'linear'` or `'sigmoid'`, and the loss should be `'mean_squared_error'`.